# altering a matrix and printing the changes in R

Tags: r

I have this matrix

```
`$seq.mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=20, ncol=2)
 colnames(seq.mat) <- c("SampleID","Sequence")
 set.seed(123)
 for (i in 1:nrow(seq.mat)) {
 seq.mat[i,1] <- paste0("Sample_", i)
 seq.mat[i,2] <- paste(sample(c("C","G","A","T"), size=1000, replace = 
 TRUE), collapse="")
 }
 seq.mat <- cbind(seq.mat, RNASeq=NA, Seq.Count=NA)`
```

I need to write a function that will detect whether a given sequence is DNA (only has "C", "G", "A", and "T" letters) or RNA (only has "C", "G", "A", and "U" letters).

If it is DNA sequence the function should:
1. Print "Seq is DNA, converting to RNA..";
2. Convert it to RNA by substituting letter "T" to "U" and save the result to *RNASeq* column of *seq.mat* object.

If it is RNA sequence the function should:
1. Print "Seq is RNA";
2. Save value of *Sequence* to *RNASeq* column of *seq.mat* object.

I know it's sloppy but I was thinking of something like this...

```
`$DNA.RNA = function(x){
 grep = as.list(grepl("[^ACGT]",seq.mat[1:20,2]))
 DNAorRNA = ifelse(grep == "FALSE", print("Seq is DNA, converting to 
 RNA.."), print("Seq is RNA"))
 DNAorRNA = as.list(DNAorRNA)
 DNAorRNA
 seq.mat[,3] = gsub("T","U",seq.mat[,2])
 }`
```

I was having a lot of trouble with this function though...and then maybe do apply or sapply the function to seq.mat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your function. I believe I solved them and that it now does what you describe in the question.

```
DNA.RNA = function(x) {
    gr <- grepl("[^ACGT]", x[, 2])
    sapply(gr, function(y){
        if(y) print("Seq is RNA") else print("Seq is DNA, converting to RNA..")
    })
    x[, 3] = gsub("T", "U", x[, 2])
    x
}

seq.mat.result <- DNA.RNA(seq.mat)
```